# Duplicate UDP packets using iptable

Tags: networking, iptables

I wanted to forward UDP packets on specific port, to multiple servers (can be on different networks). I could have created a socket and listen on that and as part of processing send received packet to multiple addresses. But this is kind of processing packet at application layer. Is this possible without listening on socket, something like configuring iptables or nftable?

Comment: Any use case to describe? I mean the description shouldn't be just "I want to duplicate packets" but also for what final purpose.

Comment: A router is sending netflows in UDP packet to a netflow collector. This collector want to distribute UDP packets to multiple sub-collectors which will do actual processing.